# Adobe Scene7 API - How do you pull assets in a specific folder?

Tags: scene7

I'm running into an issue where trying to pull a list of assets on a folder by folder basis:

The docs show that assetHandleArray is a required field for “getAssets” and the docs have a description of “The root folder to retrieve folders and all subfolders to the leaf level. If excluded, the company root is used.”

But, when we try to put a folder handle it throws an illegal handle exception.

References: 
https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/s7/ips_api/operations/r_get_assets.html

Example Request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns="http://www.scene7.com/IpsApi/xsd/2014-04-03">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <ns:authHeader>
         <ns:user>***********</ns:user>
         <ns:password>***********</ns:password>
         <ns:appName>MYAPP</ns:appName>
         <ns:appVersion>1</ns:appVersion>
      </ns:authHeader>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns:getAssetsParam>
         <ns:companyHandle>c|12345</ns:companyHandle>
         <ns:assetHandleArray>
            <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
            <ns:items>f|Path/to/folder/</ns:items>
         </ns:assetHandleArray>
      </ns:getAssetsParam>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Example Response:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <soapenv:Fault>
         <faultcode>soapenv:Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring>ipsApiFault</faultstring>
         <detail>
            <tns:ipsApiFault xmlns:tns="http://www.scene7.com/IpsApi/xsd">
               <tns:code>30000</tns:code>
               <tns:reason>Illegal AssetHandle (f|Path/to/folder/)</tns:reason>
            </tns:ipsApiFault>
         </detail>
      </soapenv:Fault>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

So how do I go about getting assets?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the answer in case anyone else tries to integrate with this service. The method that should be used to get assets by folder is the searchAssets method.

Comment: Any particular search term? Or just leave the assetHandleArray empty?